# AngularJS How would it be possible to update all radio button values to false when one is selected as true?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, radio-button

I'm pulling in from database separate true/false string values. 
The example that I'm giving is only to illustrate what I'm getting from database in reality that is a string value of either true or false I can't change this.

What I would like to do is have a single radio button display their value as selected if true and not selected if false.

This bit works fine in my answer below, however when a user selects a different button I would like to make that value 'true' and set all the others as 'false'.

I have tried all sorts of ways including ng-checked but that doesn't work with ng-model. I find radio buttons very confusing in angularJS, please could anybody help me to understand what it is that I'm supposed to be doing? Thankyou

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="sample" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/style.css">
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var MyApp = angular.module('sample', []);

        MyApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

            $scope.red = 'true';
            $scope.yellow = 'false';
            $scope.blue = 'false';
            $scope.green = 'false';
            $scope.orange = 'false';
            $scope.purple = 'false';
            $scope.black = 'false';
            $scope.pink = 'false';
            $scope.white = 'false';

        });     
    </script>  
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="container" ><!-- ng-repeat="x in alien.colours" -->

        <h3>What colour alien are you?</h3>

        <input type="radio" name="AliCol" ng-value="'true'" ng-model="red" />
        <label>Red</label>&nbsp; Value is {{red}}<br>

        <input type="radio" name="AliCol" ng-value="'true'" ng-model="yellow" />
        <label>Yellow</label>&nbsp; Value is {{yellow}}<br>

        <input type="radio" name="AliCol" ng-value="'true'" ng-model="blue" />
        <label>Blue</label>&nbsp; Value is {{blue}}<br>

        <input type="radio" name="AliCol" ng-value="'true'" ng-model="green" />
        <label>Green</label>&nbsp; Value is {{green}}<br>

        <input type="radio" name="AliCol" ng-value="'true'" ng-model="orange" />
        <label>Orange</label>&nbsp; Value is {{orange}}<br>

        <input type="radio" name="AliCol" ng-value="'true'" ng-model="purple" />
        <label>Purple</label>&nbsp; Value is {{purple}}<br>

        <input type="radio" name="AliCol" ng-value="'true'" ng-model="black" />
        <label>Black</label>&nbsp; Value is {{black}}<br>

        <input type="radio" name="AliCol" ng-value="'true'" ng-model="pink" />
        <label>Pink</label>&nbsp; Value is {{pink}}<br>

        <input type="radio" name="AliCol" ng-value="'true'" ng-model="white" />
        <label>White</label>&nbsp; Value is {{white}}<br>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Below is whats happening when you select a different button the values are updated to 'true' button but cant be set to 'false'

[image: example]

Comment: why is true and false a string?

Comment: you better consider setting it to `true` instead of `'true/false'`

Comment: Hi  I have no control over the data its coming out of the database that way, I wish I could change it.

Comment: This seems like it would be better represented by a single value, e.g. `$scope.alienColor = 'blue'/'red'/'whatever'`. Any differences in the way the data is sent to the database can be smoothed over while sending it

Comment: Thanks @kingdaro Im not sure how to do that, especially as I have to display the existing value initially, and then subsequent changes by the user.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this (a very basic one, that could be improved a lot!) is using an array of objects to do the job for you.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t3t6kueL/

In your Javascript, you could do this:

```
  var MyApp = angular.module('sample', []);

  MyApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.colors = [{
        name: 'Red', // name => For presentation
        value: 'false' // value => For toggling the group's values
      },
      {
        name: 'Yellow',
        value: 'false'
      },
      {
        name: 'Blue',
        value: 'false'
      },
      {
        name: 'Green',
        value: 'false'
      },
      {
        name: 'Orange',
        value: 'false'
      },
      {
        name: 'Purple',
        value: 'false'
      },
      {
        name: 'Black',
        value: 'false'
      },
      {
        name: 'Pink',
        value: 'false'
      },
      {
        name: 'White',
        value: 'false'
      },
    ]

    // Expose a method to change the group's values
    $scope.selectColor = function(selectedColorName) {
      // Loop through all of the colors
      $scope.colors.forEach(function(color) {
        // If this is what's being set, then set this to true
        // Note: If there are two different objects, with the same name, you will end up with 2 true values here... 
        if (color.name === selectedColorName) {
          color.value = 'true';
        // For all the others, set it to false
        } else {
          color.value = 'false';
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

This would allow you to move the logic and handling what to present to the application's code, making your HTML a bit leaner, as in:

```
<div class="container">

  <h3>What colour alien are you?</h3>

  <div ng-repeat="color in colors">
    <input type="radio" name="AliCol" ng-click="selectColor(color.name)" />
    <label>{{color.name}}</label>&nbsp; Value is {{color.value}}<br>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for this but I cannot change the way the data is being presented I have only the true or false strings to work with

Comment: Hi @Alex Szabó I like this but how do I get the initial 'true' value to show as button selected on page load? In your example they are all false but in reality one of them will be true.

Comment: @royG What does the server return? Is it an array of strings (for true & false)? If yes, you can define the objects in that order, and use indices to map the initial values. I'd have to know more about that in order for a meaningful answer

Comment: Hi @Alex Szabó yes it was returning string values as true/false but I fixed it by converting them to boolean in the end it seemed like the easiest solution Thankyou for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a single value to represent the user's selection. See the snippet below for a working example, and [see the docs for more info.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)

```js
var MyApp = angular.module("sample", [])

MyApp.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.alienColor = "blue" // set the initial value here
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sample" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- ng-repeat="x in alien.colours" -->

    <h3>What colour alien are you?</h3>

    <input type="radio" name="AliCol" value="red" ng-model="alienColor" />
    <label>Red</label>&nbsp; Value is {{red}}
    <br>

    <input type="radio" name="AliCol" value="yellow" ng-model="alienColor" />
    <label>Yellow</label>&nbsp; Value is {{yellow}}
    <br>

    <input type="radio" name="AliCol" value="blue" ng-model="alienColor" />
    <label>Blue</label>&nbsp; Value is {{blue}}
    <br>

    <input type="radio" name="AliCol" value="green" ng-model="alienColor" />
    <label>Green</label>&nbsp; Value is {{green}}
    <br>

    <input type="radio" name="AliCol" value="orange" ng-model="alienColor" />
    <label>Orange</label>&nbsp; Value is {{orange}}
    <br>

    <input type="radio" name="AliCol" value="purple" ng-model="alienColor" />
    <label>Purple</label>&nbsp; Value is {{purple}}
    <br>

    <input type="radio" name="AliCol" value="black" ng-model="alienColor" />
    <label>Black</label>&nbsp; Value is {{black}}
    <br>

    <input type="radio" name="AliCol" value="pink" ng-model="alienColor" />
    <label>Pink</label>&nbsp; Value is {{pink}}
    <br>

    <input type="radio" name="AliCol" value="white" ng-model="alienColor" />
    <label>White</label>&nbsp; Value is {{white}}
    <br>
  </div>

  {{ alienColor }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for this but I cannot change the way the data is being presented I have only the true or false strings to work with

Comment: Translate the true/false strings to the single value when the data is received, then translate it back when sending it

Comment: Yes I think that you are right, I was hoping there would be a way of dealing with it without manipulating in the controller, thanks for your help :)